# Is there a way to push ClickOnce-Releases to Github branch?

Tags: c#, git, github, tfs, clickonce

I am currently using visualstudio.com to compile my Clickonce Application but I want to automatically deploy new versions to Github where i have got a seperate branch to push releases.

I got the idea for this workaround from https://refactorsaurusrex.com/post/2015/how-to-host-a-clickonce-installer-on-github/ and it works lika a charm.

Is there a way to automate this process in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to directly publish your Clickonce Application to remote github for now.

As a workaround, you could first publish to TFS sever and copy the files , push them to another remote url (Github).

> There is an option to enable scripts to use the **OAuth token**
>   created by the build. This also enables the peristence of the
>   credentials for the Git repository to **enable scripting of git
>   commands.**
>
> - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/options#allow-scripts-to-access-the-oauth-token
> - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands

You could give a try with this extension **[Git Build Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ioz.vsts-git-build-tasks)** which rewrites the remote url with the provided OAuth token to support accessing the remote repositories for actions like git push.

Another sample for your reference: [Synchronizing TFS 2015 and VSTS with GitHub](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/synchronizing-tfs-2015-and-vsts-with-github/)

Comment: Thanks. It is now running without any flaws I can see.